# Entity Framework Code First Read and write bridge table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I just have a simple question about bridge(link) table. I have two tables that has a `many-to-many` relation and Visual Studio auto generates the bridge table with the `primary key` from those two tables. I'm a little bit confused about how to read and write data from and to the tables.

When I read data, do I query and fetch data from just one or both of the two tables that has a `many-to-many` relation? But how do I handle the bridge table?

And when I write data, the same thing here, do I save the data to one or both of the two tables that has a `many-to-many` relationship? And how do I know when I should save to the bridge table?

Very confusing and I can't find any good tutorial with code examples that I can learn from. Since I created `Controllers` with read and write `Views`, I thought this matter was taken care of in the auto genrated code, but since the bridge table is empty despite that I have added data to the other tables, I need to ask this question to get some clarity about this! Preciate if any could tell me how it works with simple example or link. Thanks!

EDIT: Table Entities for some of the tables. I'm doing this project with ASP.NET MVC.

```
public class Order
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int? ManufacturerID { get; set; }
public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Timeunit> Timeunits { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your table entities in code first?

Comment: @Ephraim I added the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above relationship will create a bridge table like:

```
public class OrderEmployeeEnrollments{
  public int OrderId {get;set;}
  public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
}
```

To Read data from `Order` table for an employee:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
  var order= context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderEmployeeEnrollments.
               Any(e => e.Employee.EmployeeId == employeeId );
}
```

To insert in `Order` table:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
   var order= new Order{
     Name="",
     ManufacturerID= 2 ,
     Manufacturer = new Manufacturer { // create  Manufacturer },
     Employees = new List<Employee> { // create list}    
  }
  context.Orders.Add(order);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

To insert 'Order' table with an existing employee:

```
 using (var context = new YourContext())
{
   var order= new Order{
     Name="",
     ManufacturerID= 2 ,         
     Employees = context.Employees.Where(e=> e.Name=="Name")    
  }
  context.Orders.Add(order);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to write in my question that I'm using ASP.NET MVC for my project. And most of the code is auto generated in the Controllers Action methods like Read and Write, but it doesn't seems to be any code to handle the bridge table. Do you know why? Does your code work in MVC?

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework works in a way that you don't have to concern yourself with the bridge table. It handles that for you as long as you have defined the relationship between entities.

In this case:

```
public class Order
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Here's an example..
WRITE:

```
    Order order = new Order();
    order.Name = "foo";
    order.Employees = _ctx.Employees.Where(e => id > 0 && id <= 5);
    _ctx.Orders.Add(order);
    _ctx.SaveChanges();
```

READ:

```
    List<Employee> employees = _ctx.Employees.Where(e => id > 0 && id <= 5);

    foreach(Employee emp in employees)
    {
       Order theOrder = emp.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == order.ID);
       if(theOrder != null)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Employee {0} has served order {1}", emp.ID, theOrder.ID);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to write that I'm doing this project in ASP.NET MVC and I just wonder if your code works inside the Controllers Action Methods?

Comment: If I don't need to concern about the bridge table, why is it empty?

Comment: Just to clarify things, Entity Framework works even if it is not MVC. MVC is a design pattern that's on the architecture level. And yes, this works for ASP.NET MVC :)